# Getting Dates and Each record against date from same table

Tags: php, mysql

I need a task to be done in one query let me show u the structure of my table

**NEWS**

---

news_id
news_date 
news_topic
news_desc

What i want to do is display records like this

news_date
      All news records Pertaining to same same date ......

for e.g

23 March , 2012
All news of  23 march like topic desc

22 March , 2012
All news of  22 march like topic desc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to only pull out a certain days news then:

```
SELECT * FROM news WHERE DATE(news_desc) = '2012-03-23'
```

to filter for a specific topic

```
SELECT * FROM news WHERE DATE(news_desc) = '2012-03-23' AND news_topic LIKE "%topic%"
```

If you just want to order the data by date (so you can output in order

```
SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY DATE(news_desc) DESC;

SELECT * FROM news WHERE news_topic LIKE "%topic%" ORDER BY DATE(news_desc) DESC
```

For the php you could do something like:

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY DATE(news_desc) DESC;"
$mysqlRes = mysql_query($q);
$currentDate = false;
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($mysqlRes)) {
  if($currentDate != $row->news_date) {
    echo $row->news_date."<br />";
    $currentDate = $row->news_date;
  }
  echo $row->news_topic."<br />";
}
```